# Display KendoUI Window Within a KendoUI ListView

Tags: listview, window, kendo-ui

I'm a new user of KendoUI and I want to display a small portion of data in a ListView but I want to have a button or a link that when I click it I want it to show the full data of my item in a Window, I hope someone could help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following DataSource:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url     : ...
        }
    },
    schema   : {
        model: {
            id    : "ProductID",
            fields: {
                ProductID   : { nullable: true },
                ProductName : { type: "string" },
                UnitPrice   : { type: "number" },
                Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
                UnitsInStock: { type: "number" }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

That defines a series of fields: `ProductID`, `ProductName`... and I want to display `ProductName`, so my template is:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <div class="product-view k-widget ob-product-view">
        <div class="edit-buttons">
            <a class="k-button k-button-icontext" href="\\#" id="${uid}">
                <span class="k-icon k-i-search"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <dl>
            <dt>Product Name</dt>
            <dd>#:ProductName#</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
</script>
```

That displays a button and I include the `uid` of the field as `id`. This will allow me to retrieve the item when the button is clicked.

Then I define the window as:

```
<div id="ob-win" class="product-view k-widget">
    <dl>
        <dt>Unit Price</dt>
        <dd data-bind="text: UnitPrice"></dd>
        <dt>Units In Stock</dt>
        <dd data-bind="text: UnitsInStock"></dd>
        <dt>Discontinued</dt>
        <dd data-bind="text: Discontinued"></dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

and I create it as:

```
var win = $("#ob-win").kendoWindow({
    title  : "Details",
    visible: false
}).data("kendoWindow");
```

making it initially hidden.

Then I create a handler for the button as:

```
$(document).on("click", ".k-button-icontext", function (e) {
    var uid = $(this).attr("id");
    var elem = listView.dataSource.getByUid(uid);
    kendo.bind($("#ob-win"), elem);
    win.open().center();
});
```

that gets the `uid` of the clicked element, then gets the data from the DataSource using the `uid` stored in the `id` and binds this data to the window created before. Finally I open the window just in case it was close.

A running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/YmRpa/